# SQL: If date in one table is within 12 months of a date in another table then Yes else No

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One for tests recorded and one for pre test questionnaire.
I am wanting to select from my test recorded table and have a column for 'Pre test Questionnaire completed?' which would contain yes or no

A questionnaire must have been recorded within 12 months prior to doing a test. So, if I do a questionnaire on 01/01/2023 and do a test on 10/01/2023, the result would be yes for the column 'Pre test Questionnaire completed?'. If the dates where the other way round and I did a test on 01/01/2023 and a questionnaire on 10/01/2023, I would want the result to be no as the questionnaire was not recorded within 12 months of a test.

The tables join via a PersonID.

Table: tests recorded

| Person | Test Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 01/01/2023 |
| 2222 | 05/01/2023 |
| 3333 | 10/01/2023 |

Table: Questionnaire recorded

| Person | Q Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 10/12/2022 |
| 2222 | 20/05/2023 |

Desired output would be:

| Person | Q Date | Q'nnaire completed in last 12months? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 10/12/2022 | Yes |
| 2222 | 20/05/2023 | No |
| 3333 | 10/01/2023 | No |

Desired output because person 1111 has  questionnaire completed before the test, the other 2 don't.

Worth noting a person can have several questionnaires and tests.

If anyone is able to help with the correct join/ case statement for my additional column in the select that would be great. I've tried so many different dateadd/datediff and can't manage to work the logic.

Thanks

**EDIT:

I am using SQL Server. The following is the query I have tried:

```
SELECT wt.[WalkTestPK]
      ,wt.[PersonID]
      ,wt.[CompletionDate]
      , case 
      when (Q.[Completion time]) >= dateadd(day,365,wt.[CompletionDate]) then 'yes'
      else 'no'
      end as [Was a questionnaire completed within 12 months prioir to this test?]
      FROM [WalkTests] wt
  left join Questionnaires Q on Q.[Service Number] = wt.PersonID
```

Some clarification on multiple tests and questionnaires - An individual is required to do a test twice a year. A questionnaire should be filled in before a test and is valid for 12 months and therefore one questionnaire should cover 2 tests. What I want to do is select the data from my test table and query the questionnaire table to see if a questionnaire was filled out within the 12 months before a test.

In summary, if a record exists in the Questionnaire table for the PersonID who has done a test in the test table, I want to know if the record in the questionnaire table is within 12 months prior to the test date.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What RDBMS do you use (for example SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL...)? And could you please add the query you have tried?

Comment: Can you use the same table format also for the expected result?

Comment: *Worth noting a person can have several questionnaires and tests.* - probably worth showing this in your sample data then?? How would you know which questionnaire related to which test per person ID?

Comment: Hello @JonasMetzler , thank you for the reply. I have added an edit area at the bottom of my post which I hope will clear things up for you.

Comment: Hello @Stu , thank you for the reply. I have added an edit area at the bottom of my post which I hope will clear things up for you.

Comment: Hello @jarlh , thank you, desired output table corrected.

Comment: You have not specified how to handle multiple tests and questionnaires. Do you want to consider only the most recent items?

Comment: Hi @O.Jones , I want to consider all items on both sides. If a test is recorded today I need to know if a questionnaire was completed within 12 months prior to the test date of today. If a questionnaire was recorded 5 year ago, its older than 12 months and therefore todays test would be 'no' questionnaire completed. If there was a q'nnaire from 6 months ago, then 'yes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a record exists in the Questionnaire table for the PersonID who has done a test in the test table, I want to know if the record in the questionnaire table is within 12 months prior to the test date.

This is the easiest case: you just want to know **whether** a relevant questionnaire exists for each test, so your output is just yes/no. You only join the questionnaires that you actually want to count, then you say Yes if a test has one and No if it doesn’t (`null`). Since there may be multiple matching questionnaires, you can avoid spread rows using distinct (or group by but I’m lazy)

```
select distinct T.WalkTestPK
    , T.PersonID
    , T.CompletionDate
    , [Questionnaire within 12 months] = iif(Q.ID is null, 'No', 'Yes')
from WalkTests T
    left join Questionnaires Q on Q.[Service Number] = T.PersonID
                              and Q.[Completion Time] >= dateadd(year, -1, T.CompletionDate)
```

If you need to output the completion date from the Questionnaires table, your result rows will spread. To avoid this, use `group by` and output `max(Q.[Completion Time])` to show the latest matching questionnaire.

If you need to output even more stuff from the questionnaire, not just the latest date, you can use an ordered `outer apply`. This will give you all columns from the single newest questionnaire per person (or `null` if there wasn’t any within 1 year):

```
select T.WalkTestPK
    , T.PersonID
    , T.CompletionDate
    , [Questionnaire within 12 months] = iif(Q.Id is null, 'No', 'Yes')
    , Q.[Completion Time]
    , Q.ShoeSize
    , Q.Whatever
    , Q.SomeOtherColumn
from WalkTests T
    outer apply (select top 1 *
                 from Questionnaires Q
                 where Q.[Service Number] = T.PersonID
                     and Q.[Completion Time] >= dateadd(year, -1, T.CompletionDate)
                 order by Q.[Completion Time] desc) Q
```

(note I’m just writing this dry without standing up test data, there may be syntax errors or other mistakes)

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great. I used your first query and it was nearly perfection! I just needed to add 'and Q.[Completion Time] <= T.CompletionDate' to the join to work exactly how I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```sql
SELECT WalkTests.WalkTestID,
       WalkTests.PersonID,
       WalkTests.TestDate,
       CASE WHEN MAX(Questionnaires.QDate) > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, WalkTests.TestDate) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS [Completed within 12 months] 
FROM WalkTests
    LEFT JOIN Questionnaires ON WalkTests.PersonID = Questionnaires.PersonID
GROUP BY WalkTests.PersonID, WalkTests.TestDate
ORDER BY WalkTests.PersonID
```

You want to group by the `WalkTests` columns you want to display and select the `MAX(Questionnaires.QDate)` and then check if that is greater than 1 year before the test date.

Also, you will need to make sure you include the WalkTests PK in the query just so you don't just assume people who've taken multiple tests didn't test on the same day--i.e., you only want questionnaire records being grouped.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a4a0/1